# Exact position of scroll in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, scroll-position

How to get exact position of scroll in GridView ?
`gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition()` is not good because it only shows values like 0, 2... and I need accurate float number.

Comment: too bad there is no other solution, cause I need it since api 7+

Comment: You seriously are targeting pre-Froyo? Why? http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html -- less than 1% of devices. Cut your losses and move on.

Comment: I wouldn't but my employer wants to ;(